# How to insert document metadata into the contents?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export, metadata

I can set up the metadata of an output PDF via `File → File info`, but when using `Type → Text variables → Define` (as hinted [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/text-variables.html)), something like Metadata → Title yields a "no intersecting link" - apparently this option is used for image captions and *not* for metadata of the InDesign document itself.

So, how to keep some text in the InDesign document and one of its metadata fields in sync?

Comment: You want to keep what in sync? Text file content and .indd metadata?

Comment: @Joonas .indd metadata and some text field contents _inside_ the very same file

Comment: Right. You could do that with javascript to a point, but the problem is triggering the sync. Maybe with an extension or external methods it would be possible to make an automatic sync, but with javascript you are limited to a manual button click sync. Then again, if you had a script for saving the file, that would pretty much eliminate the issue. So you could trigger a script to save the file and update the metadata at the same time...

Comment: @Joonas Phew, _that_ sounds pretty complicated for something I'd consider essential... Did Adobe really not implement this?

Comment: I can perhaps kinda see why you'd want that, but I'd also say that what you trying to do is not super common or at least necessary in most cases, because this would mostly be very static data.

Comment: @Joonas It is not so static if you're creating a document(ation) template... and it _is_ rather annoying to spot wrong metadata just _after_ publishing the PDF

Comment: Yea, but I'd claim that usually it is quite static. It's not too often that the author of the document changes during a project, for instance.

Comment: @Joonas It should remain static once created, yes, but as mentioned, at the moment either the metadata in the template remains empty and may not be used at all or an explicit instruction to correctly fill it out (and not to forget that when copy-pasting a document for a "new" project - yes, some users do that) has to be put somewhere...

Comment: Either way, there really aren't many options there.

Comment: You will find that many things you consider to be important are missing from application X, its not that it couldnt be useful for somebody. Its just not part of the design, period. Thats why software have a scripting and api layers so you can help yourself. I could list 10,000 things adobe does wrong

Comment: @joojaa Make that 10,001 :P

Answer (score 2):

InDesign doesn't have the ability to do what you are asking out of the box unfortunately (I too consider this to be essential).

Below is a quick and dirty way to sync up a text variable named `Document Title` with the "Document Title" in the File Info metadata. (hint: define and use the text variable in a template)

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
if (doc.textVariables.item('Document Title').isValid){
    doc.textVariables.item('Document Title').variableOptions.contents = doc.metadataPreferences.documentTitle;
}
else {
    // there's no variable named 'Document Title'
}
```

There are [other `metadataPreferences`](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcsjs5.5/pc_MetadataPreference.html) you can use as well. A more determined person than be could probably write a script to check all the metadata and fine a corresponding text variable.